# Why does my screen flicker when scrolling the image below?

Tags: image-processing

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this, but does anyone here know why my screen flickers (not in a broken kind of way) when scrolling on this [image from Claude Mellan](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/ca/Claude_Mellan_-_Face_of_Christ_-_WGA14764.jpg)

Comment: This  creates a Moiré pattern because of all the fine lines.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moiré_pattern